# WhatsApp notifications show contact name instead of sender-defined name

Tags: whatsapp.app

When I get a message with WhatsApp and my iPhone is locked, I cant see sender's name as they set it in their own WhatsApp. I see the name which saved in my Contacts. Already 3 days like that... I want to solve this problem. I want to see the ***sender's name*** on the lock screen, not the Contact name.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to not have that person in your contacts or have their Whatsapp name in contacts. You can't have them both in your contacts and also just display the regular Whatsapp username as far as I know.

Comment: This sounds like something that happened with the latest version of whatsapp. until then, it was indeed possible. and it wouldn't make sense to remove that person from the contacts.

Comment: @rockyraw I haven't been keeping up with the recent changelogs of WhatsApp (mainly cause telegram is better :P ) other than the whole eula/terms/legalstuff update that happened a bit ago so I couldn't say if its a new change or even a change at all. 

All I can say is at the time of answering, that's all that was possible and still seems to apply even now (i just checked quickly and don't see an option).

Also Mehriban remember to accept an answer once you are happy with the results. :)